# How to wrap a json file with jsonp callback

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm trying to parse a Json file response, but I'm having troubles.

My javascript is:

```
var url=encodeURIComponent("http://localhost:8080/repositories/rep_name?query=some_query&Accept=application/sparql-results+json");   
    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type:'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            // do something
            $('#doQuery').html("QUERY");
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            _UTILS.showModal("error", textStatus, 300, 100);
            }
        });
```

But I got this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" in chrome. I  think the problem is that the response my server gave me is not wrapped with jsonp callback, because when I check my response, it is shown as a plain json format like this:

```
{
  "head" : {
    "vars" : [ "child", "parent", "count" ]
  }
}
```

instead of this:

```
callback({
  "head" : {
    "vars" : [ "child", "parent", "count" ]
  }
})
```

But when I check the request url from ajax, it actually has the "&callback=" parameter appended to the end of the url, something like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/repositories/rep_name?query=some_query&Accept=application/sparql-results+json&callback=jQuery21105273823537863791_1443406558624&_=1443406558625
```

So why does it still give me that error?

One thing to notice is that the server sends back a .srj file, but it is in json format, I don't know if this has anything to do with the error. Also, I can't use `dataType: 'json', otherwise I will get "XMLHttpRequest cannot load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." error. I don't think I can change the server though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSONP callback parameter is a hint to the server that you want the JSON wrapped in a callback. If the server is not specifically set up to listen to the parameter and serve JSONP when needed, then it will ignore that parameter.

Since there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header present on the server, using pure JSON instead of JSONP is also a no-go.

I would double check to make sure there isn't some other way to request JSONP from the server, otherwise if you don't have access to the code on the server, and you can't request JSONP through other means, you are unfortunately out of luck.

Comment: actually I'm running the server myself, but I have limited access to the source code. The server is run by executing an .sh file which is using the embedded tomcat to deploy a .war file. So in this case, how should I modify the server?